MJML Fluid Template Generation loops
I'm attempting to supply a string value to 'values', e.g. "Example1;Example2". However the logic below is incorrect. I get no generated output form this section in my response.
    <mj-section>
      <mj-raw> 
        {% assign arrayItems.text = values | split:";" %}
      </mj-raw>
      <mj-raw> 
        {% for item in arrayItems.text %} 
      </mj-raw>
          <mj-column>
            <mj-text font-family="sans-serif">{{item}}</mj-text>
          </mj-column>
      <mj-raw> {% endfor%} </mj-raw>
    </mj-section>

c# Template value defintion
var variables = 
{"passcode": "12345",
 "expires": "12:30 Smith",
 "values": "TestLine;TestLine2;"
}

        foreach (var variable in variables)
        {
                context.SetValue(variable.Key, variable.Value);   
        }

Within my logic I have also tried different logic such as changing the array definition. example below
{% assign arrayItems = values | split:";" %}

as different fluid documentation defines arrays in different ways.
Directly assigning the array as an string array works correctly however I need a way of translating any string values (as my request only accepts string inbound) and can accept any number of different string arrays named differently.
